# What is the best local sql database for a .net client application?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, desktop

I am working on an application that needs to use a local sql database.  The database needs to be encapsulated in a file because they need to be able to easily move the data accross the network, onto a usb stick, burned onto a cd/dvd, etc.

Our older apps all used access, which has worked great for us, but I'd like to use the newer .net tools such as linq, which I believe just leaves sql ce edition (which doesn't seem to support x64).

How have you dealt with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Compact, as of [3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=dc614aee-7e1c-4881-9c32-3a6ce53384d9&displaylang=en), [does support x64](http://blogs.msdn.com/stevelasker/archive/2008/08/07/sql-server-compact-3-5-sp1-released.aspx) (and it works well for desktop apps).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from compact edition, SQLite has a strong following.  Not sure how well it works with linq/64-bit, though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what sort of performance you need on this app, but if you need your entire database to be completely portable, you could go with sqlite - .NET can hook into it, and since the entire DB will be housed in one file it would be extremely easy to move around.